# Limpiar datagrid vinculada a un ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Tengo un datagrid (CalculoRutas) que se alimenta de un ObservableCollection

```
vmRutas = new ViewModelRutas();

            CalculoRutas.DataContext = vmRutas;
```

Clase:

```
public class ViewModelRutas
{
    public ObservableCollection<Patrulla> RutasPatrullas { get; set; }

    public ViewModelRutas()
    {

        RutasPatrullas = GeneratePatrullas();
        
    }
    
    private ObservableCollection<Patrulla> GeneratePatrullas()
    {
        try
        {
               //Más código
               
               public void LimpiarRutasPatrullas()
               {
                     RutasPatrullas.Clear();
               }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("MainWindowViewModel " + e.Message);
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

El problema es que cuando llamo al LimpiarRutasPatrullas, me limpia el DataGrid pero me lanza un error: "Colección modificada; puede que no se ejecute la operación de enumeración" ocurre cuando intentas modificar una colección mientras estás en medio de un bucle de enumeración (por ejemplo, mientras estás iterando sobre los elementos de la colección)"

He probado poner el datagrid (CalculoRutas.ItemSource=null) y da el mismo error.

¿Alguna idea de como puedo solventarlo?

Saludos

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! y el codigo de LimpiarRutasPatrullas?

Comment: CalculoRutas.DataContext = vmRutas; esto suena raro.. si eso es la grilla, no deberia ir al vmRutas, si no a la coleccion dentro del VM

Comment: Debes agregar más código, te falta la parte donde está el `foreach`

Comment: Hola comunidad, voy a seguir las sugerencias, actualizo sobre el código en cuestión que el problema estaba en el foreach, lo he removido y todo va bien.